# Firebase has not been correctly initialized and the "GoogleService-Info.plist" file in the required folder

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, dart, initialization

My app working correctly on Android but I have exception on iOS.

The iOS build was done on Codemagic.

Dev. environment - Windows Flutter Dart.

What is missing?

**The exception on the following line in mainCommon**

```
FirebaseApp firebaseApp = await Firebase.initializeApp();
```

**mainCommon -**

```
Future<void> mainCommon() async  {
  try {
    loggerDBND("START - MainComminStart0");
    FirebaseApp firebaseApp = await Firebase.initializeApp();

    loggerDBND("START - MainComminStart1");
    FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_messageHandler0);

    loggerDBND("START - MainComminStart2");
    globals.messaging = await FirebaseMessaging.instance;

    loggerDBND("START - MainComminStart3");
    globals.messaging.requestPermission();

    loggerDBND("START - MainComminStart4");
    await globals.messaging.subscribeToTopic("messaging");

    loggerDBND("START - MainComminStart5");
    globals.messaging.getToken().then((value) {
      print("Token -" + value.toString() + "-");
    });

    loggerDBND("START - MainComminStart6");


  } on Exception catch (exception) {
    loggerDBN("mainCommon - exception"+exception.toString() );
  } catch (error) {
    loggerDBN("mainCommon - error" + error.toString());
  }
```

**The exception -**

```
main- error[core/not-initialized] Firebase has not been correctly initialized. Have you added the "GoogleService-Info.plist" file to the project? 
    
View the iOS Installation documentation for more information: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/installation/ios
```

**File "GoogleService-Info.plist" location** - ....\ios\Runner

Answer (score 2):

In a similar issue from the past, adding `GoogleService-Info.plist` to the correct folder by dragging and dropping the file using Apple's Xcode was the solution.

Another user provided a windows [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61683861/3064893)

Comment: But I don't have Xcode. Codemagic build the .ipa.
I moved the file using Windows Move

Comment: I understand. I added a link to another answer that shows a workaround for windows that might help

Comment: I open the project.pbxproj file and didn't find GoogleService-Info.plist 
Is it mean, the plist will not be in the build?

Comment: I updated the files and waiting for the build to finish