# Error (Xcode): Build input file cannot be found: '/Users/builder/clone/ios/GoogleService-Info.plist'

Tags: ios, flutter, codemagic

I am attempting to generate an iOS build(IPA file) for my Flutter application on Windows 10 using Code Magic. Unfortunately, I have encountered an error during the build process. Attached is a screenshot of the error. I would greatly appreciate your assistance in resolving this issue.

[image: Image of Error code]

**Error**

> Failed to build iOS app Error (Xcode): Build input file cannot be
> found: '/Users/builder/clone/ios/GoogleService-Info.plist'. Did you
> forget to declare this file as an output of a script phase or custom
> build rule which produces it?
>
> Encountered error while building for device.

I tried to solve using this - [Where to save GoogleService-Info.plist in Flutter without Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56407299/where-to-save-googleservice-info-plist-in-flutter-without-xcode) but didn't find any luck. Can you please explain the process if this has worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

The `GoogleService-Info.plist` file is normally required in an IOS app when you are using the Firebase SDK in your app.

In your case are you using 1 or more Firebase packages in your Flutter app? If so you need to follow the instructions on the Firebase website which should generate this required file for you: https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=ios#install-cli-tools

Comment: The link you have mentioned says that it requires a MacOS. However, I have windows with me as mentioned in the question

Comment: @Lakshmi if you are using Codemagic, you have the ability to use VNC to get a remote desktop to the Mac in Codemagic that you are running your build on, see:  https://blog.codemagic.io/remote-access-to-virtual-mac-build-machine/
and you can then use the instructions I linked to or the SO answer you linked to, to setup the plist and then push those changes from the CM build machine you're VNC'd into, back up to the remote git repo you are using (Github, BitBucket, etc).